# What is UILocale for localization in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, localization, locale

I am using Delphi XE3’s built-in method to localize my application. In this article, [How applications find localized resource DLLs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Localizing_Applications#How_applications_find_localized_resource_DLLs), it mentions "UILocale". Is it a property of the application, or the Form? I try to search in the help document but cannot find anything.

Comment: “*Is it a property of the application, or the Form?*” - Neither. It is a property of the user’s OS configuration instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, Is there any document on this?

Comment: I search online but still cannot find info about UILocale, I can see Moriza has a command called UILocale